# How to extract Icons from Exe or DLL byte array / memory stream?

Tags: c#, dll, icons, exe, extract

I need to get icons from .exe and .dll file streams directly without temporary files.

This file stream is obtained from the MSI package "Icon" table.

I was able to successfully extract Icon from ".ico" file stream from the MSI package "Icon" table with this code:

```
public static Icon BytesToIcon(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
     return new Icon(ms);
    }
}
```

but I have no clue of how I could read icons from .exe and .dll file streams directly. Please help me to look into right direction.

The question is about reading Icons from Byte[] fileStream.
There is no file. And the goal is to read Icons from that stream without temporary files.

Other similar question is about "Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath)"
It is not suitable for me because there is no file path.

### This is not a duplicate, because similar question was marked as duplicate due to a moderator's mistake.

Update:
**[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998533/how-to-extract-icons-from-exe-or-dll-file-stream-in-c) was marked as "duplicate" by moderator "L.B" by mistake. Moderator did not check updated question with my clarification on "why it wasn't actually" a duplicate. Unfortunately site does not allow to contact users, and after question is marked as duplicate by someone on their own thought - the question will be spoiled without a chance of appeal.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract Icons from Exe or DLL file stream in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998533/how-to-extract-icons-from-exe-or-dll-file-stream-in-c)

Comment: not duplicate, read carefully full text of question

Comment: some silly people down-voting without an explanation, "brave enough".

Comment: TI is a duplicate of *your* question (that I'd voted to reopen, as *that* was not a duplicate of the other). [Per the Help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) the correct thing to do is to *edit the question that is on hold*, not to ask it again.

Comment: Hi, many thanks. I have edited that question and it was still marked as duplicate for several days after that. Seems that no one had re-view it and maybe already lost in question history. I am only for following correct procedures, if those work, of course. Why I opened this question again - is because it still is marked as duplicate and I have found an answer for my question, which I wanted to share here in case someone will face the same problem as me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a [project library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16178/IconLib-Icons-Unfolded-MultiIcon-and-Windows-Vista) that does everything exactly what I have asked for.
The library has method to Load .exe/.dll as a memory stream.
I can convert my byte[] array to memory stream object as follows:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(myByteArray);

//and then load that MemoryStream with IconLib Load method:

MultiIcon multiIcon = new MultiIcon();
multiIcon.Load(stream)

//Iterate through different resolution icons under index 0
List<Icon> iconList = new List<Icon>();
foreach(IconImage iconImage in multiIcon[0])
{
 iconList.Add iconImage.Icon
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that MultiIcon simply copies the stream to a file before opening it.